# jQuery calculation is not working from external file, returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing simple jQuery calculation like below, which is working as expected in plain HTML page, if I try to put the same in **external file** run, `delivered` variable value showing error as **NaN**

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qf9Lqz59/2/)**

I do not know where am I doing wrong :) Any help please?

May be anything to do with `parseInt` or something?

**HTML (UPDATED)**:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
  <section> 
        Total audience = <span class="total-audience"></span>
        <br>
        Delivered = <span class="delivered"></span>
  </section>    
  <script src="Scripts/plugins.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**from External script (init.js) file:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var totalAudience = "105,000";  
    var delivered = totalAudience * 60 / 100;

    jQuery('.total-audience').html(totalAudience);
    jQuery('.delivered').html((delivered).toFixed(0));

});
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine.

Comment: How do you load your external file?

Comment: @Roysh... I am loading the external file as `<script src="Scripts/init.js"></script>`... at the bottom of all scripts

Comment: Have you checked it's loading? Is it in the `<head>` tag? Have you tried any debugging like place an `alert` in scope?

Comment: And if you open the dev tools in your browser and watch the console, do you get any errors?

Comment: @Jamiec... I am not getting any errors in the console :(

Comment: @Roysh... I have placed the scripts just before `</body>` tag

Comment: There is not enough info here for anyone to help you. Your code works in jsfiddle but when your javascript is in an external file you get `NaN` from `(delivered).toFixed(0)` - that just cant happen, there must be something else going on (your code different in some way)

Comment: do you mean `</body>` or `<body>`? Try to place the scripts in the `<head>` tag. 
And are you sue the script is loading? Suppose you add `alert('hi')` in the script, do you see it on the page?

Comment: I am placing at before body tag ends (`</body>`)

Comment: Your external file - it doesnt contain `<script>` tags, or does it?

Comment: And If I adding variable value as `var delivered = "150"`, it is working... may be something wrong with the parseInt or something?

Comment: 1) Try to place before `</head>` instead.
2) Try the other things I've suggested

Comment: @Roysh it makes no difference if the file is in the head or at the end of the body - it doesnt matter where it is - if it uses `$(document).ready...`

Comment: But are you sure it is loading at all?

Comment: @Reddy - your code does not contain a `parseInt` - hence my comment about it must be different code to this question!!!

Comment: can you show us the the exact order how you're loading jquery and the init.js. Please update the main post with the whole source. I tested your code and it's working properly , even from an external js file.

Comment: There seems to be no `reached` variable defined inside the provided code. Ahh... I see in the JS fiddle, why use different code on SO and JSF? Nvm

Comment: Hi all, I have updated the content and **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf9Lqz59/2/)** as well... please check... now in jsFiddle also not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry All**,

It was because of **typo** at the `variable` because of comma symbol... thats why it is not working...

I just removed comma from `var totalAudience = "105000";`

Thanks for your time.